# TYPO3 after update v9 -> V10 second URL page not found

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

After the update from v9 to v10.4.12 I have a problem with the access to the web page.

If I use

> https://www.country-radio.eu

it works fine, but if I use

> https://country-radio.eu

it doesn't work anymore.
I have set

> baseURL = https://www.country-radio.eu

> SYS trustedHostsPattern = .*

But I got a "Page not found" error.
If I try to access https://country-radio.eu/info3.php it works and shows the php info.

What I have to do, to get the root URL working again under v10?

**Edit:**
I could not figure out how to do it with TYPO3. Therefore I implemented the redirect with IIS,

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to add a rewrite rule in the .htaccess file in the document root and redirect non-www requests to www:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^country-radio.eu$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.country-radio.eu/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I am using IIS and tried already a URL rewrite, but it doesn't work for some reasons. The question is still, what has changed in V10, that it is not working anymore?

Comment: I have no idea what has changed, sorry.